# How to display 2 divs in line while 1 is centered

Tags: html, css

I've been working on this quite a while, but i still can't get it to work. I want 2 divs to be displayed in line, while one of them is centered. I can acquire this by making one of them absolute and the other one with margin:0 auto;, but on small screens the centered div will overlap the absolute div.

Example:
[JsFiddle Example Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v0sww57L/)
                                                                                                     So is it possible not to overlap the 2 divs on small resolutions?

Here is my code:

```css
#absolute{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    
    border:2px solid;
    text-align:center;
}
#center{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
  
    border:2px solid;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="absolute">The absolute div</div>
<div id="center">The centered div</div>
```

Comment: On Smaller resolutions, you want them stacked?

Comment: I want them to be next to each other, without any space between them.

Answer (score 0):

You should **add a parent wrapper** with a `padding-right` equal to the width of the absolute element. Also add `left:0;` to the absolute element

here's the code :https://jsfiddle.net/v0sww57L/2/

Comment: Yes, i thought at this but the center div is not really on the center of the page...I want it to be centered if the screen resolution allows it, and if not, then it should be next to the absolute div(without any space between them).

Comment: well you could add a padding-left  equal to padding right to center the alignment. but you would have large unnecesary padding. You could probably find a way to validate your styling with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to this one, and it should hopefully work well. Change the width to anything on the sidebar that you had shown in your snippets and still they will not overlap and look nice.     You don't need to make it absolute, just float it to left and set a width for it.

```
#absolute{
width:50%;
height:100%;
float: left;
border:2px solid;
text-align:center;}

#center { 
height:200px;
border:2px solid;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}
```